# Why do these sequences show up so much in proofs and counter examples?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I have drawn on a piece of paper a bunch of different sequences in an $\ell_p$ space that converge to a constant sequence. Each of the elements in this sequence in an $\ell_p$ space are eventually constant.

There are two sequences that are bothering me. The first is the sequence that is always constant, but then 0 at ever $2^n$ term. So

> $x_1=c,x_2=c,x_3=c,x_4=0,...,x_8=0,...x_{16}=0,...$

In this fashion. This sequence seems to somehow converge to c even though I can always find an N such that $x_N=0$ and so $x_N$ would lie outside of any epsilon band around c. Why is it that I can say this sequence converges to c? Would it still converge if it were every $2n$ term that was 0?

The other sequence that bothers me is the sequence that is always 0 but then "spikes" at the $2^n$ term to c. So

> $x_1=0,x_2=0,x_3=0,x_4=c,x_5=0,...,x_8=c,...,x_{16}=c,....$

This sequence also bothers me. If I want to claim that a sequence in $\ell_p$ converges to c and I find this element in my sequence, does my sequence still converge to c?

These examples seem to come up a lot and they always throw me off because I never think of them when I need to. Why are they so important? Why do they come up in proofs and as counter examples. I even see them C[0,1] as functions that peak at certain values of x and are otherwise 0.

Comment: Those are essentially the same sequences - one is $y=c(1,1,1,\dots)-x$ where $x$ is the first sequence and $y$ is the seond. What does this have to do with $\ell_p$, by the way? These are just sequences, not elements of $\ell_p$ for any $p$ other than $p=\infty$. A sequence is in $\ell_p$ if $\sum |x_i|^p<+\infty$, and neither of these sequences is in $ell_p$.

Comment: I think of $f \in \ell_p $ as $f= (f(k))_{k=1}^{\infty}$. And so I imagine an element of an $\ell_p$ space to be a sequence indexed by $\mathbb{N}$. The norm of the $\ell_p$ space maps each $f$ to some real number. This has to do with $\ell_p$ because I couldn't imagine the same question coming up in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: But that's not what $\ell_p$ means. The above are sequences, and $\ell_p$ consists of sequences, but $\ell_p$ does not consist of *all* sequences, and, in particular, does not contain either of the sequences you've mentioned above.

Comment: Oh no you are right, c cant be constant like that. Sorry, this is my first course in analysis. I think the sequences above are in $\ell_p$ if I change it to c = $\frac{1}{n^2}$. Also are you sure neither of the sequences above are in $\ell_p$? This is really getting at the heart of my question. It seems like the sequence where every $2^n$ term is a constant might actually be in $\ell_2$ for example.

Comment: But then in both cases $x_n\to 0$ by the usual definition of limit.

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing a sequence of elements $y_1,\dots,y_n,\dots\in\ell_p$, which is a sequence of sequences, with a single element of $\ell_p$, which is a sequence of real numbers?

Comment: You are right. Ok so then, what about the sequence where every $2^n$ term is a constant. Everywhere else the sequence is 0.  Is this in an $\ell_p$ space? What about the sequence where every term is such that $x_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$. But then the $2^n$ term of $x_n$ turns out to actually be $\frac{1}{n}$. Then the subsequence of $x_n$ that is $x_{2^{n}}$ is not in $\ell_1$ but is $x_n$ in $\ell_1$?

Comment: No, by definition, that isn't in $\ell_p$ because $\sum |x_i|^p$ doesn't converge - the terms are $|c|^p$ for infinitely many $i$.

Comment: But they are so "sparse" does that not affect anything?

Comment: Why would it affect anything? Just consult the definition. Definitions are your friend.

Comment: Here is an example of where it matters: Suppose that $a_n \geq 0$ and that  $\sum _{n=1}^\infty a_n <  \infty $. Give an example showing that $lim sup_{n\rightarrow \infty}na_n > 0$ is possible. In this case the sequence to use is one where all terms are 0, except sparsely populated in the sequence are terms $\frac{1}{n^2}$